Balance disappeared on phantom after buying more of the same coin. Please help?
E4c contract
0x60170ce53739745b21a336114534440bda46b2cb
Purchased this. Phantom wouldn’t let me sell. Bought more 1100 ish to see if it would let me do that. It did. When I purchased, my initial balance of 206k disappeared. Thought what the heck. Tried to buy again to verify. Bought 700 and my previous balance of 1100 disappeared. Bc scanners aren’t showing any outgoing that I can see.
My slippage was 2.5%
Link to initial purchase of 206k.
https://basescan.org/tx/0x59e29cc84988a3b6e140f4a5e90b61d1756b83867bb7473779631232785bf0c3
I’m not sure what’s going on but I’d like to solve this. If anyone here can help it would be greatly appreciated.
